# Need help to create login system for gym clients

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application, fitness

I'm creating an application for my gym that I own and for my clients through Android Studio, using Java. I am using Firebase for my database. I would like to keep track of the days the my clients show up and also maybe a like a countdown timer of days until their membership ends.

I would like assistance with how I can have a button start their session every time they enter the gym. I currently use Google Forms to have them input an id code that links to google sheets to manually record their days that way, a link with Google Sheets would also be efficient.

Comment: Wow...this may not be the right forum for that. SO is basically working out existing code problems...but not necessarily.

Comment: As @ChrisCatignani was saying, this is a good forum to solve particular problems after you're stuck at something and already tried to solve it. I'd suggest you unpack your problem into several little problems. It may help to start with something that works only on the phone without firebase or sheets, and then progressively incorporate those things. If you have little experience in native android dev I'd recommend taking a look at https://flutter.io which has a smoother learning curve and can also create iOS and web applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a good bit of experience in programming to do this.  At a high level, you would need to code a user interface that takes as input a user id and maybe password.  Then you would call an API for Google sheets and add the following fields: userid, date, and time.  Then, you could either create another app to analyze this data or a built in Google Sheets function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have started the application and have very well advanced in other parts. The calling and API for Google sheets sounds like a good route, would you have a reference or place where I can go about learning how to do that part?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Comment: Excellent, thanks for you your help Christian B